# AccessViolationException when Call C++ dll on C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am implementing a C++ Dll for C#. But when I run my program, an AccessViolationException will occur. Here is the code. 
in C++:

```
extern "C" DLLIMPORT double __cdecl ErrorCalculate(double* pBufferA, double* pBufferB,__int32 length)
{
    __m128d xfdLoadA;
    __m128d xfdLoadB;
    const double* pA = pBufferA;
    const double* pB = pBufferB;

    //do somthing

    for(int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
    {

        xfdLoadA = _mm_load_pd(pA);//error occur at this line
        xfdLoadB = _mm_load_pd(pB);

        pA+=2;
        pB+=2;
        //  do somthing
    }
    //  do somthing
}
```

in C#:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "ErrorCalculate", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern double ErrorCalculate(double[] pBufferA, double[] pBufferB, int length);

public void frameProcessing(Image<Gray, byte> frame){
    //do something

    SSE4 sse4 = new SSE4();
    unsafe
    {
        //length of samplePoint is the same as tempPoint
        fixed (double* sample = samplePoint)
        {
            fixed (double* test = tempPoint)
            {
                errorSum = sse4.ErrorCalc(sample, test, length);
            }
        }
    }

    if(errorSum<=threshold)
    {//do something}
}
```

frameProcessing will be called several times. Sometimes the error will occur at first time I call frameProcessing, sometimes second time. And I found that error occur at _mm_load_pd(pA). I'm sure that pA and pB are not null(Value of the two array can be printed out). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be DLLEXPRT in the C++ part?

Comment: You don't seem to ensure that `_mm_load_pd` argument is 16-byte aligned.

Comment: @milbrandt I'm sorry that it's a little mistake. I define it as __declspec (dllexport) and name it as DLLIMPORT

Comment: @VTT I made pA and pB 16-byte aligned and it seems to work well! Thanks very much!

Comment: That is not good enough.  The code will crash randomly, so it may well *look* like you fixed the problem.  But you didn't, the core problem is that the double[] is only guaranteed to be aligned to 4 in 32-bit mode, to 8 in 64-bit mode.   And it may change after a collection.  You *must* use `_mm_loadu_pd`.  That's unpleasant but at least it isn't that expensive anymore on modern cores.  Do look at System.Numerics.Vector.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for pointing out the problem. I've changed `_mm_load_pd` to `_mm_loadu_pd`. It's helpful. Thanks again!